# write dataframe columns past nan values in specific column based on 2 dataframe relationship

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know the question is worded horribly but I can't think of how to word it any better.

I have two dataframes, one containing the original data:

```
    {2016: {1: 88698.0,
  2: 86725.0,
  3: 80426.0,
  4: 74888.0,
  5: 71659.0,
  6: 67431.0,
  7: 63613.0,
  8: 60174.0,
  9: 59495.0,
  10: 59487.0,
  11: 59118.0,
  12: 59542.0,
  13: 61170.0,
  14: 63785.0,
  15: 65038.0,
  16: 67441.0,
  17: 68188.0,
  18: 69303.0,
  19: 70224.0,
  20: 70163.0,
  21: 71522.0,
  22: 73707.0,
  23: 75002.0,
  24: 76487.0,
  25: 78806.0,
  26: 81444.0,
  27: 84114.0,
  28: 84274.0,
  29: 86701.0,
  30: 87051.0,
  31: 89298.0,
  32: 91461.0,
  33: 93937.0,
  34: 96308.0,
  35: 96803.0,
  36: 98718.0,
  37: 99343.0,
  38: 100494.0,
  39: 101260.0,
  40: 101153.0,
  41: 99668.0,
  42: 97139.0,
  43: 97203.0,
  44: 95940.0,
  45: 96969.0,
  46: 98608.0,
  47: 96332.0,
  48: 94736.0,
  49: 90970.0,
  50: 87938.0,
  51: 82082.0,
  52: 79481.0,
  53: nan},
 2017: {1: 75212.0,
  2: 68024.0,
  3: 64087.0,
  4: 58824.0,
  5: 52226.0,
  6: 50006.0,
  7: 46975.0,
  8: 46794.0,
  9: 42855.0,
  10: 42021.0,
  11: 41884.0,
  12: 40281.0,
  13: 39117.0,
  14: 37985.0,
  15: 37120.0,
  16: 36968.0,
  17: 36702.0,
  18: 38486.0,
  19: 39051.0,
  20: 40589.0,
  21: 44099.0,
  22: 47631.0,
  23: 49984.0,
  24: 51726.0,
  25: 55653.0,
  26: 57663.0,
  27: 59409.0,
  28: 62820.0,
  29: 63324.0,
  30: 64788.0,
  31: 64693.0,
  32: 66452.0,
  33: 69349.0,
  34: 70697.0,
  35: 76470.0,
  36: 78805.0,
  37: 77624.0,
  38: 75268.0,
  39: 74695.0,
  40: 75892.0,
  41: 75930.0,
  42: 74942.0,
  43: 75824.0,
  44: 74628.0,
  45: 72058.0,
  46: 71113.0,
  47: 70602.0,
  48: 71898.0,
  49: 72186.0,
  50: 68760.0,
  51: 65931.0,
  52: 65441.0,
  53: nan},
 2018: {1: 59224.0,
  2: 55546.0,
  3: 51355.0,
  4: 50126.0,
  5: 45962.0,
  6: 42438.0,
  7: 39840.0,
  8: 39370.0,
  9: 37844.0,
  10: 35470.0,
  11: 33731.0,
  12: 32671.0,
  13: 33416.0,
  14: 33039.0,
  15: 33260.0,
  16: 32937.0,
  17: 33599.0,
  18: 35737.0,
  19: 37453.0,
  20: 38314.0,
  21: 40159.0,
  22: 44152.0,
  23: 47971.0,
  24: 51381.0,
  25: 55825.0,
  26: 58905.0,
  27: 61242.0,
  28: 62724.0,
  29: 61766.0,
  30: 63514.0,
  31: 63533.0,
  32: 66825.0,
  33: 65732.0,
  34: 68240.0,
  35: 70572.0,
  36: 71835.0,
  37: 72966.0,
  38: 74556.0,
  39: 76592.0,
  40: 78223.0,
  41: 79895.0,
  42: 79209.0,
  43: 79793.0,
  44: 80800.0,
  45: 79795.0,
  46: 78203.0,
  47: 77027.0,
  48: 75356.0,
  49: 72124.0,
  50: 68584.0,
  51: 67402.0,
  52: 65576.0,
  53: nan},
 2019: {1: 63624.0,
  2: 62046.0,
  3: 58091.0,
  4: 54316.0,
  5: 51765.0,
  6: 52033.0,
  7: 48140.0,
  8: 46787.0,
  9: 44772.0,
  10: 43806.0,
  11: 44905.0,
  12: 45564.0,
  13: 46906.0,
  14: 48134.0,
  15: 50554.0,
  16: 51797.0,
  17: 53271.0,
  18: 54197.0,
  19: 57114.0,
  20: 60312.0,
  21: 60509.0,
  22: 63388.0,
  23: 66265.0,
  24: 69530.0,
  25: 70905.0,
  26: 72313.0,
  27: 72288.0,
  28: 73153.0,
  29: 74967.0,
  30: 76430.0,
  31: 79261.0,
  32: 82623.0,
  33: 86492.0,
  34: 90041.0,
  35: 92856.0,
  36: 93701.0,
  37: 96520.0,
  38: 95368.0,
  39: 96264.0,
  40: 96355.0,
  41: 95794.0,
  42: 95282.0,
  43: 94817.0,
  44: 95536.0,
  45: 92914.0,
  46: 89160.0,
  47: 88321.0,
  48: 86443.0,
  49: 88099.0,
  50: 85469.0,
  51: 82634.0,
  52: 82188.0,
  53: nan},
 2020: {1: 82784.0,
  2: 81804.0,
  3: 80581.0,
  4: 77236.0,
  5: 77976.0,
  6: 71822.0,
  7: 68726.0,
  8: 68132.0,
  9: 64557.0,
  10: 61529.0,
  11: 61379.0,
  12: 59424.0,
  13: 59134.0,
  14: 59027.0,
  15: 56780.0,
  16: 57442.0,
  17: 56835.0,
  18: 59376.0,
  19: 61625.0,
  20: 62697.0,
  21: 64240.0,
  22: 67329.0,
  23: 66282.0,
  24: 68967.0,
  25: 71331.0,
  26: 74599.0,
  27: 76823.0,
  28: 80348.0,
  29: 82388.0,
  30: 84404.0,
  31: 86713.0,
  32: 89336.0,
  33: 89295.0,
  34: 90833.0,
  35: 95222.0,
  36: 97380.0,
  37: 96141.0,
  38: 97890.0,
  39: 101959.0,
  40: 101842.0,
  41: 99897.0,
  42: 98325.0,
  43: 98391.0,
  44: 95828.0,
  45: 94889.0,
  46: 92887.0,
  47: 92562.0,
  48: 91718.0,
  49: 87637.0,
  50: 83927.0,
  51: 81596.0,
  52: 75146.0,
  53: 72777.0},
 2021: {1: 66048.0,
  2: 59818.0,
  3: 57610.0,
  4: 56053.0,
  5: 51545.0,
  6: 48649.0,
  7: 43491.0,
  8: 41246.0,
  9: 41199.0,
  10: 41029.0,
  11: 41269.0,
  12: nan,
  13: nan,
  14: nan,
  15: nan,
  16: nan,
  17: nan,
  18: nan,
  19: nan,
  20: nan,
  21: nan,
  22: nan,
  23: nan,
  24: nan,
  25: nan,
  26: nan,
  27: nan,
  28: nan,
  29: nan,
  30: nan,
  31: nan,
  32: nan,
  33: nan,
  34: nan,
  35: nan,
  36: nan,
  37: nan,
  38: nan,
  39: nan,
  40: nan,
  41: nan,
  42: nan,
  43: nan,
  44: nan,
  45: nan,
  46: nan,
  47: nan,
  48: nan,
  49: nan,
  50: nan,
  51: nan,
  52: nan,
  53: nan}}
```

and then one which is just the first dataframe.diff():

```
    {2016: {1: nan,
  2: -1973.0,
  3: -6299.0,
  4: -5538.0,
  5: -3229.0,
  6: -4228.0,
  7: -3818.0,
  8: -3439.0,
  9: -679.0,
  10: -8.0,
  11: -369.0,
  12: 424.0,
  13: 1628.0,
  14: 2615.0,
  15: 1253.0,
  16: 2403.0,
  17: 747.0,
  18: 1115.0,
  19: 921.0,
  20: -61.0,
  21: 1359.0,
  22: 2185.0,
  23: 1295.0,
  24: 1485.0,
  25: 2319.0,
  26: 2638.0,
  27: 2670.0,
  28: 160.0,
  29: 2427.0,
  30: 350.0,
  31: 2247.0,
  32: 2163.0,
  33: 2476.0,
  34: 2371.0,
  35: 495.0,
  36: 1915.0,
  37: 625.0,
  38: 1151.0,
  39: 766.0,
  40: -107.0,
  41: -1485.0,
  42: -2529.0,
  43: 64.0,
  44: -1263.0,
  45: 1029.0,
  46: 1639.0,
  47: -2276.0,
  48: -1596.0,
  49: -3766.0,
  50: -3032.0,
  51: -5856.0,
  52: -2601.0,
  53: nan},
 2017: {1: nan,
  2: -7188.0,
  3: -3937.0,
  4: -5263.0,
  5: -6598.0,
  6: -2220.0,
  7: -3031.0,
  8: -181.0,
  9: -3939.0,
  10: -834.0,
  11: -137.0,
  12: -1603.0,
  13: -1164.0,
  14: -1132.0,
  15: -865.0,
  16: -152.0,
  17: -266.0,
  18: 1784.0,
  19: 565.0,
  20: 1538.0,
  21: 3510.0,
  22: 3532.0,
  23: 2353.0,
  24: 1742.0,
  25: 3927.0,
  26: 2010.0,
  27: 1746.0,
  28: 3411.0,
  29: 504.0,
  30: 1464.0,
  31: -95.0,
  32: 1759.0,
  33: 2897.0,
  34: 1348.0,
  35: 5773.0,
  36: 2335.0,
  37: -1181.0,
  38: -2356.0,
  39: -573.0,
  40: 1197.0,
  41: 38.0,
  42: -988.0,
  43: 882.0,
  44: -1196.0,
  45: -2570.0,
  46: -945.0,
  47: -511.0,
  48: 1296.0,
  49: 288.0,
  50: -3426.0,
  51: -2829.0,
  52: -490.0,
  53: nan},
 2018: {1: nan,
  2: -3678.0,
  3: -4191.0,
  4: -1229.0,
  5: -4164.0,
  6: -3524.0,
  7: -2598.0,
  8: -470.0,
  9: -1526.0,
  10: -2374.0,
  11: -1739.0,
  12: -1060.0,
  13: 745.0,
  14: -377.0,
  15: 221.0,
  16: -323.0,
  17: 662.0,
  18: 2138.0,
  19: 1716.0,
  20: 861.0,
  21: 1845.0,
  22: 3993.0,
  23: 3819.0,
  24: 3410.0,
  25: 4444.0,
  26: 3080.0,
  27: 2337.0,
  28: 1482.0,
  29: -958.0,
  30: 1748.0,
  31: 19.0,
  32: 3292.0,
  33: -1093.0,
  34: 2508.0,
  35: 2332.0,
  36: 1263.0,
  37: 1131.0,
  38: 1590.0,
  39: 2036.0,
  40: 1631.0,
  41: 1672.0,
  42: -686.0,
  43: 584.0,
  44: 1007.0,
  45: -1005.0,
  46: -1592.0,
  47: -1176.0,
  48: -1671.0,
  49: -3232.0,
  50: -3540.0,
  51: -1182.0,
  52: -1826.0,
  53: nan},
 2019: {1: nan,
  2: -1578.0,
  3: -3955.0,
  4: -3775.0,
  5: -2551.0,
  6: 268.0,
  7: -3893.0,
  8: -1353.0,
  9: -2015.0,
  10: -966.0,
  11: 1099.0,
  12: 659.0,
  13: 1342.0,
  14: 1228.0,
  15: 2420.0,
  16: 1243.0,
  17: 1474.0,
  18: 926.0,
  19: 2917.0,
  20: 3198.0,
  21: 197.0,
  22: 2879.0,
  23: 2877.0,
  24: 3265.0,
  25: 1375.0,
  26: 1408.0,
  27: -25.0,
  28: 865.0,
  29: 1814.0,
  30: 1463.0,
  31: 2831.0,
  32: 3362.0,
  33: 3869.0,
  34: 3549.0,
  35: 2815.0,
  36: 845.0,
  37: 2819.0,
  38: -1152.0,
  39: 896.0,
  40: 91.0,
  41: -561.0,
  42: -512.0,
  43: -465.0,
  44: 719.0,
  45: -2622.0,
  46: -3754.0,
  47: -839.0,
  48: -1878.0,
  49: 1656.0,
  50: -2630.0,
  51: -2835.0,
  52: -446.0,
  53: nan},
 2020: {1: nan,
  2: -980.0,
  3: -1223.0,
  4: -3345.0,
  5: 740.0,
  6: -6154.0,
  7: -3096.0,
  8: -594.0,
  9: -3575.0,
  10: -3028.0,
  11: -150.0,
  12: -1955.0,
  13: -290.0,
  14: -107.0,
  15: -2247.0,
  16: 662.0,
  17: -607.0,
  18: 2541.0,
  19: 2249.0,
  20: 1072.0,
  21: 1543.0,
  22: 3089.0,
  23: -1047.0,
  24: 2685.0,
  25: 2364.0,
  26: 3268.0,
  27: 2224.0,
  28: 3525.0,
  29: 2040.0,
  30: 2016.0,
  31: 2309.0,
  32: 2623.0,
  33: -41.0,
  34: 1538.0,
  35: 4389.0,
  36: 2158.0,
  37: -1239.0,
  38: 1749.0,
  39: 4069.0,
  40: -117.0,
  41: -1945.0,
  42: -1572.0,
  43: 66.0,
  44: -2563.0,
  45: -939.0,
  46: -2002.0,
  47: -325.0,
  48: -844.0,
  49: -4081.0,
  50: -3710.0,
  51: -2331.0,
  52: -6450.0,
  53: -2369.0}}
```

What I am trying to do is calculate, for all columns in any row where 2021 is NaN, the next value row by taking the value in the normal dataframe and adding the next down value from the .diff() dataframe. So, for example, 2020 for week 12 would be 61379 (row 11 in normal df) + (-1955.0, row 12 from the .diff() df)

TIA

Comment: While asking a question, it's always better to provide the data in an easy reproducible way. Something like: `df["slice"].to_dict()`

Comment: thanks @ThePyGuy, I'll do that and edit the question!

Answer (score 0):

Same logic like before

```
out = df1.mask(df1[2021].notna(),df1+df2.shift(-1),axis=0).fillna(df1[[2021]])
```

Comment: ahhh I did my shift in the wrong direction! thank you

Comment: however it looks like it only does that for one subsequent row, how do i make it do that for the remainder of the df?

Comment: I should also clarify that I don't need this to fill values in the 2021 column, just 2020